# Сортировка списка объектов

Tags: python, список

Как отсортировать список объектов в python?
Допустим, такой список:

```
array = [
  {'x': 9, 'y': 357}, 
  {'x': 19, 'y': 357}, 
  {'x': 20, 'y': 357}, 
  {'x': 21, 'y': 357}
]
```

Нужно отсортировать (по возрастанию) по ключу объекта `x`

Comment: Главный навык программиста - умение гуглить: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

если нужно изменить исходный список, то используйте функцию `sort`:

```
array.sort(key=lambda dict_:dict_["x"])
```

а если нужно создать новый, то функцию `sorted`

```
array2 = sorted(array, key=lambda dict_:dict_["x"])
```